# SQL query question on selecting grade for student's academic history

Tags: sql

If I have a `student_grade_history` table containing past grade history for students, for example:

```
student | course   | year       | grade 
--------+----------+------------+----------
steve   | Math1A   | 2018spring |  A+   
steve   | English  | 2018spring |  B-   
steve   | Science  | 2018spring |  B+  
steve   | Biology  | 2018spring |  C
```

and I would like to count the grade each student received  A+, A , A- into grade A and B+,B,B- into grade B and C+,C,C- into grade C.

I am able to create a table like the following:

```
student | year       | # of A received | # of B received | # of C received 
--------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
steve   | 2018spring |       1         |        2        |        1
```

However, I am trying to creating a table that has the following format based on student_grade_history table, but I cannot think of a way to do it.

```
student | year       | grade | count  
--------+------------+-------+------
steve   | 2018spring |   A   |   1      
steve   | 2018spring |   B   |   2      
steve   | 2018spring |   C   |   1
```

Can I get some hints how to approach this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select student, year, left(grade, 1) as grade, count(*)       
from student_grade_history
group by student, year, left(grade, 1);
```

Not all databases support `left()` (but most do).  All have the functionality, even if it goes by a slightly different syntax.